# How to override grid.php block or cart.php block to remove some items from shopping cart

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

I want to filter the products (excluding products with some attributes) when the shopping cart is loaded.  What is the best way to achieve this.  I have looked into overriding getItems function of Magento/checkout/block/cart/grid.php, but cannot load product repository in this file.  Or using an observer is good?? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

for your requirement, you can use below event `checkout/cart/index` action.

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove product when add product to cart and show message. I suggest you should preference class `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` to change flow of function `addProduct()`.

For example:

In `etc/di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart" type="Custom\Module\Model\Cart"/>
```

In `Custom\Module\Model\Cart.php`:

```
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{
    $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
    $productId = $product->getId();

    if (//check your condition here) 
    {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Show message you want here...');
        return ;
    }
    ...
}
```